# Toolbar won't show above keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitoolbar

I cannot get the toolbar to show above (just like apple has with a done button) the keyboard. Can anything think of why it isn't showing? Like the image below.

[image]

.h

```
@interface CustomerNotesController : UITableViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
{
    UIToolbar *noteToolbar;
    IBOutlet UITextView *note;
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *note;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *noteToolbar;
```

.m

```
@synthesize note, noteToolbar, delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [note setDelegate:self];
    [note becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"EDITING");
    if (noteToolbar == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Creating toolbar");

        noteToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];
        noteToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNote:)];

        UIBarButtonItem *clearButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(clearNote:)];

        UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(saveNote:)];

        noteToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, clearButton, extraSpace, doneButton, nil];
        NSLog(@"Items: %@", noteToolbar.items);
    }

    NSLog(@"Current field: %@",textView);
    NSLog(@"keyboard: %@", noteToolbar);
    textView.inputAccessoryView = noteToolbar;
}
```

LOGS

```
2012-04-11 17:31:00.148 MyApp[28892:fb03] EDITING
2012-04-11 17:31:00.148 MyApp[28892:fb03] Creating toolbar
2012-04-11 17:31:00.149 MyApp[28892:fb03] Items: (
    "<UIBarButtonItem: 0x10dc3420>",
    "<UIBarButtonItem: 0x10dc3480>",
    "<UIBarButtonItem: 0x10dc34e0>",
    "<UIBarButtonItem: 0x10dc3540>"
)
2012-04-11 17:31:00.149 MyApp[28892:fb03] Current field: <UITextView: 0x10d94f40; frame = (5 5; 310 140); text = 'This is sample text'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x10d95170>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2012-04-11 17:31:00.150 MyApp[28892:fb03] keyboard: <UIToolbar: 0x10dc2820; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10dc2730>>
```

Comment: Try setting these in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: @Legolas I tried a few placements of this code. I did the view did load, keyboardWillAppear, and the textViewDidBeginEditing and textViewShouldBeginEditing.

Comment: @QwertyBob You guys are not understanding the question... It can be done as I have had it working before in other apps. The tool bar is placed just above the keyboard just like Apple does it on their keyboards.

Comment: @Computer I really don't see what's wrong with your code. It looks correct, and the inputAccessoryView should show up. What's the deal with `[note becomeFirstResponder];`  ?

Comment: @Legolas I'm wanting the keyboard to show when the view is displayed and to have the cursor already in the textview so the user can just begin typing. I have tried taking that out and manually selecting the textview but still no change.

Comment: @Legolas please add your first comment as the answer... That did it. I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried it yesterday... Maybe I accidentally had the `note.delegate = self` commented out or something.

Comment: @Computer Glad the issue is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting these in the `viewDidLoad` method !

Comment: To clarify for anyone else having this issue. The probably reason it didn't work for me before when I put it in the view did load was that I probably didn't have the `textview.delegate = self;` set. Infact it may have been commented out.

Answer (score 3):

//use this method

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    textView.inputAccessoryView = yourToolBar;

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.  The keyboard is a system-controlled UIView that you cannot directly control.  The OS is going to lay the keyboard view on top of all other views to ensure it has the correct focus to gather user input.

Can you provide more background on why you would want to do this?  even if you did figure out a way to make the views behave as you describe it will almost certainly be rejected by Apple for violating the Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: huh? I don't think you understand the issue. I'm trying to get a toolbar to show up above (not in front of) the keyboard with a done button and a few other buttons. Just like apple has on their keyboard. It can be done as I have seen it before.

Comment: I think you guys should user method that i have posted above.